# ValueError while creating a ColumnTransformer for a pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, random-forest

I am trying to create a data pipeline to process and fit my training data. I am using `ColumnTransformer` for the pre-processing, but I get the error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I believe I am not clear on how to create a `FunctionTransformer`.

Code:

```
X = school_data.drop(['result'], axis=1)
y = school_data['result']

clean_data = FunctionTransformer(clean_school_data, kw_args=X)

column_pipeline = ColumnTransformer([
    ("imputer", IterativeImputer(), selector(dtype_include=np.number)),
    ("clean data", clean_data, selector(pattern=None))
])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)

model_pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('features', column_pipeline),
    ('merge_datasets', merge_datasets),
    ('get closest school', closest_school), 
    ('random_forest', RandomForestClassifier(random_state=2))
])      

def clean_school_data(data):
    data.columns = map(str.lower, data.columns)
    data=data.rename(columns={'pws_id':'pwsid'})
    data = data.loc[:,~data.columns.duplicated()]
    return data
```

Comment: Adding a toy example of input data would help others to reproduce the error and eventually suggest a solution.

Comment: Also please work to provide a _minimal_ example; here, if the problem is just the `FunctionTransformer` as you expect, you should be able to demonstrate the same error without the `ColumnTransformer` and `Pipeline`. Also, always provide the full error traceback.